# AngularJS How to configure a view which is without Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a web app, and *routeProvider* to navigate between views it is configured:

```
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            templateUrl: 'signUp/register.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        **.when('/sitelocator', {
            templateUrl: 'sitelocator/sitemap.html',
        })**
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}
```

Where "/sitelocator" I have a HTML file which contains a map (API google maps)
and I do not need controller.
The problem is that only *templateUrl* the page does not load correctly, how I could solve?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.344, 114.048),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });
    var polyOptions = {
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.45,
        editable: true
    };
    // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
    // markers, lines, and shapes.
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        markerOptions: {
            draggable: true
        },
        polylineOptions: {
            editable: true
        },
        rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
        circleOptions: polyOptions,
        polygonOptions: polyOptions,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
            // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
            // mouses down on it.
            var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
                setSelection(newShape);
            });
            setSelection(newShape);
        }
    });
    // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
    // map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
    buildColorPalette();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: could you say more about "does not load correctly" ? what are the errors, what's your problem with it ?

Comment: Likely a problem in how you initialize map. Show how it is configured. It won't work if you are using `onload` handler and needs to be initialized from directive

Comment: I want to go on /sitelocator through routing of AngularJs. The page HTML at issue is HTML which contains google maps API and it does not have a controller. I posted the inizializiation of map

Answer (score 0):

Angular Router allows views without controllers.

http://jsbin.com/wuxuwuxiga/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: 'hi'
        });
}

angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(config);
```

A number of issues could occurring one of which may be you're not getting to the right path in the route. Are your `href` values prefixed with `/`? All of your states are defined from the web root (as they should be in most cases). Make sure your links are also pointing from the web root.

```
<!-- Wrong -->
<a href="sitelocator">Site Locator</a>
<!-- Right -->
<a href="/sitelocator">Site Locator</a>
```

Hope that helps.